# Class MongoDB\Driver\Query' not found, MongoDB installed

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx, yii2

For this installation:

- Nginx 1.11.10
- Yii Framework 2.0.12 ("yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "^2.0")
- PHP MongoDB library (mongodb 1.2.9, compatible with PHP Version: PHP 5.4.0 or newer)
- PHP 5.4.16
- Plesk Onyx 17.0.17
- No IPTables rules

Strangely enough they function when you visit the website the first time. I can also see data pulled from the Mongo database. But when visiting another page within 10-20 seconds, this error will appear:

25403#0: *170 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Query' not found in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/Command.php on line 284" while reading response header from upstream

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
```

Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Query' not found
1. in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/website.com/vendor/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/Command.php at line 284

```
    try {
        $this->beginProfile($token, __METHOD__);

        $query = new \MongoDB\Driver\Query($this->document, $options);
```

However, if you wait another 10-20 seconds, the website works just fine.

Comment: Did you install the mongo extension, or the mongodb extension? Check phpinfo() output please.

Comment: PHPinfo says: mongodb version 1.2.9

Comment: I am having this issue. I do have the mongodb.so, its enabled on the php.ini, it is not showing on phpinfo(). The vendor files are there. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in a yii2 docker alpine nginx image, doing this:

```
FROM local/dmstr/php-yii2:latest-alpine-nginx

RUN apk --update add autoconf g++ make && \
    pecl install mongodb
RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-mongodb.ini
```

You must install mongodb and then create an ini file for the extension on your system's php extensions directory, like I did. Remember to put `extension=mongodb.so` on it.